# Threejs Visualization

Tags: javascript, flask, three.js, visualization

So now i have a database stored at a specific local path in a sqlite3 connection. I want to get data from the database and create a mapping system where each categorical field i give represents planets in the system and the moons around each planet represent the numerical columns, so basically for each planet there are muliple moons so for each categorical field, i have multiple numerical fields and make it clickable to pass the data to a dash instance                                                 the categorical fields are - ['TranType', 'PrimaryCurrencyCode', 'MessageTypeIdentifier', 'ProcCode', 'MerchantType'                                                                                                                                                                                      the numerical fields are - ['TransactionAmount', 'OutstandingAmount', 'CurrentBalance', 'TotalOutStgAuthAmt']

```
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "./OrbitControls.js";

// Fetch data from Flask backend
fetch("/get_data")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    init(data); // Initialize scene with data
    animate(); // Start animation
  });

// Create a scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Create a camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = 20;

// Create a renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Create an invisible axis
const axis = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(axis);

// Create planets
const planets = [];
const moons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  const planet = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff })
  );
  planet.position.set(i * 8 - 20, 0, 0);
  axis.add(planet);
  planets.push(planet);

  const moonGroup = new THREE.Group();
  planet.add(moonGroup);

  const radius = 2; // Radius of the moon's orbit
  const angleIncrement = (2 * Math.PI) / 6; // Angle increment between each moon

  for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    const angle = j * angleIncrement;

    const moon = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.3, 16, 16),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff })
    );

    // Set the position based on the radius and angle
    moon.position.set(radius * Math.cos(angle), 0, radius * Math.sin(angle));

    moonGroup.add(moon);
    moons.push(moon);
  }
}

// Add orbit controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

// Render the scene
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  axis.rotation.y += 0.01;

  planets.forEach((planet, index) => {
    planet.rotation.y += 0.01;

    const moonGroup = moons.slice(index * 6, (index + 1) * 6);
    moonGroup.forEach((moon, moonIndex) => {
      const angle = moonIndex * ((2 * Math.PI) / 6);
      const radius = 2;

      // Set the position based on the radius and angle
      moon.position.set(radius * Math.cos(angle), 0, radius * Math.sin(angle));
    });
  });
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

This is how i set up my backend
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, jsonify
import sqlite3

from dash_instance import create_dashapp


server = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
dash_app = create_dashapp(server)

@server.route('/')
def home():
   return render_template('index.html')

@server.route('/dashboard')
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/dashboard/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   server.run(debug = True)
```